# Alphabetically sorting data from http services in angular

Tags: angular, sorting

I'm trying to alphabetically sort data which will be presented in a select form field.
The data will be extracted from an HTTP service, and includes four categories: bread, vegetables, fruits and dairy. This is the pipe I use:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByChildPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;

  }
}
```

This is is the ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderByChildPipe } from 'src/app/pipes/order-by-child.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form-component',
  templateUrl: './product-form-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form-component.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$:any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product-categories').subscribe(res=> {
      this.categories$ = res;
      console.log(this.categories$)
    })
  }

}
```

This is the relevant part from the HTML view:

```
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" *ngFor="let c of categories$ | orderBy:'name'" type="text" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="">{{c.bread.name}}</option>
            <option value="">{{c.dairy.name}}</option>
            <option value="">{{c.vegetables.name}}</option>
            <option value="">{{c.fruits.name}}</option>
            


        </select>
    </div>
```

And this is the db.json:

```
  "product-categories": [
    {
      "bread": {
      "name":"Bread" 
      },
      "vegetables": {
        "name":"Vegetables" 
      },
      "dairy": {
        "name":"Dairy" 
      },
      "fruits": {
        "name":"Fruits"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Now I know i'm not doin it correctly since I'm populating all of the options manually and this is why the pipe doesn't work. Also, I feel it is a more tedious approcach. I just need someone to point me to the correct way of doing this. The final result should be all the options sorted alphabetically (using the pipe) once the user selects the category box. Meaning:

Bread
Dairy
Fruits
Vegetables

Thanks!

Comment: use `localeCompare` instead `<` to compare in the `sort` callback

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is not the pipe itself, but the data structure (hint: use types to ensure that you are doing the correct thing :)).

Let's assume that the following data structure coming from the HTTP request is the following (copied from your db.json):

```
[
      {
        bread: {
          name: 'Bread',
        },
        vegetables: {
          name: 'Vegetables',
        },
        dairy: {
          name: 'Dairy',
        },
        fruits: {
          name: 'Fruits',
        },
      },
    ]
```

This is basically an array containing exactly one object with different keys. In order to transform this into an array where sorting makes sense, you should extract the values from it:

```
this.categories$ = Object.values(res[0]);
```

After that you can use `*ngFor` in order to loop over this array and create an `<option>` element for each of these entries (you did this for your select):

```
<select id="category" type="text" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | orderBy: 'name'" [value]="c.name">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

After that your pipe works as expected.

**Hints:**

- You should always use types. Even if you don't know the exact type of the array, that should be sorted, you know at least that it should be an array.
- The trailing dollar sign is usually a convention used for defining observables. You can just assign your observable to `categories$` and use the `async` pipe. This way you won't have to subscribe manually to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did that (this.categories$ = Object.values(res[0]);) and now it gives me an error of: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(7053)

Comment: `.get()` is a generic function, which will implicitly return type `any`. You should try to define the returned type by setting `.get<YourDefinedType>()` so actually receive a typed value from this call.

Answer (score 0):

product-categories is an array with an unique element, why not create an array with the name?

```
obs$=this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product-categories')
categories$=this.obs$.pipe(map((res:any[])=>{
   const obj=res[0]; //<--get the only element
   const names=Object.keys(obj).map(key=>obj[key].name).sort()
   return names;
   })
)
```